# No module named 'requests' - Django deployment onto Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Deployed some new code into an app on Heroku and now showing the following message: `No module named 'requests'` . The app was working fine before, so this has to be something I changed.

Before I show the code there is 2 things that I noticed: my Procfile & requirements files are not visible from Visual Studio (can be seen from Sublime Text Editor). Recently started using VS and only noticed it now. Not sure if this is of importance here.

I am not sure where the error is coming from so I left below traceback, Procfile and requirements.txt files.

Let me know if I need to add something else.

**Traceback**

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 111, done.
Counting objects: 100% (111/111), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (80/80), done.
Writing objects: 100% (81/81), 129.38 KiB | 2.59 MiB/s, done.
Total 81 (delta 23), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.10.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote:  !
remote:  !     A Python security update is available! Upgrade as soon as possible to: python-3.10.7
remote:  !     See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote:  !
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.10.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Found another file with the destination path 'Logo.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
remote:        139 static files copied to '/tmp/build_42cf0f4b/staticfiles', 5 unmodified, 378 post-processed.
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 92.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v53
remote:        App deployed to Heroku
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.5.2
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
defusedxml==0.7.1
diff-match-patch==20200713
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.6
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-import-export==2.8.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
Flask==2.1.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupPy==1.14
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
numpy==1.23.1
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.10
pandas==1.4.3
Pillow==9.2.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
pymongo==4.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-decouple==3.6
pytz==2022.1
PyYAML==6.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tablib==3.2.1
tzdata==2022.1
Werkzeug==2.1.2
whitenoise==6.2.0
xlrd==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
```

Comment: add `requests==2.28.1` to  **Requirements.txt**

Comment: thanks it worked! Another question if you dont mind, because I seem to be running into an another similar error. It seems that my requirements.txt file is not up to date. What would be the comment to update it? (feel free to post this as an answer, I am happy to accept it by the way)

Comment: Do you mean you want to  Update all the libraries in your requirements.txt ?

Comment: Could you show the error you're  getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `requests` in **Requirements.txt** like this :

```
requests==2.28.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `request` by running the below command

```
pip install requests
```

Then update your `Requirements.txt` just run

```
pip freeze > Requirements.txt
```

This will add all libraries that you have used in the project including the newly installed.